# Getting error on deployment in capistrano 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, capistrano3

My deploy.rb file is

```
    lock '3.2.1'
    set :application, 'my_app'
    set :repo_url, 'path_to_git_repo.git'
    set :deploy_user, 'root'
    set :deploy_to, '/var/www'
    set :branch, 'master-final_code'
    set :scm, :git
    set :deploy_via, :copy
    set :format, :pretty
    set :stages, ["staging"]
    set :log_level, :debug
    set :pty, true
```

my staging.rb is

```
    set :stage, :staging
    role :app, %w{root@my_ip_add}
     %w{[root]}
    server 'my_ip_add', user: 'root', roles: %w{app}
    set :ssh_options, {
        forward_agent: false,
        auth_methods: %w(password),
        password: 'my_pass',
        user: 'root'
    }
```

Getting error:

```
Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What should i do in this case? Should i edit config. of deploy.rb or staging.rb? Or is there any problem of ssh key?

Answer (score 0):

This is an ssh/git problem. There's two parts to the error message:

```
Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive)
```

This means "I tried to connect to the git repo, but I couldn't." It doesn't say so explicitly, but it's in the format of an error from SSH. The part in brackets is telling you how it tried to authenticate: first using [SSH keys](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSH_keys), then via a keyboard prompt.

```
fatal: Could not read from remote repository
```

Because git couldn't connect to your git repo, it couldn't retrieve your code. Thus, your deployment fails.

---

One concerning thing about your code is that you're trying to deploy as root. This is a horrifically bad idea; not only are you storing your root credentials in your config files, but if you (or the Capistrano authors) have a bug in the deploy tasks or config, you could destroy the system. It's far better to create a `deploy` user with permissions for the deploy directory. That way, if something goes wrong - or someone gains access to the `deploy` account - they don't have complete access to the server. You should also be aware that many systems [disallow root logins via SSH](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/security-tip-disable-root-ssh-login-on-linux/), often by default.